# How to fry tortillas for poori?

Tags: bread, deep-frying

Whenever I deep fry tortillas to use as poori (as in halwa poori) it becomes very crispy and hard. I want to know how can I keep ot soft?
I use uncooked tortillas.

Comment: I admit that I don't know much about Indian cuisine, but somehow this situation sounds strange. Are you sure that it is supposed to be soft, because deep fried things are normally hard and crispy? And if it indeed has to be soft, are you sure that it can be done with a tortilla?

Comment: I don't know about this general case, but in general : (1) Don't cook it as long.  (2) Serve it before it has a chance to steam out or cool off.

Comment: Flour or corn tortillas? Are you making them yourself? I have never seen uncooked tortillas in a store.

Comment: Local groceries in the SW USA have raw flour tortillas. It's also easy enough to find masa prepared for corn tortillas. I suspect OP is using flour tortillas. Raw flour tortillas only need about 30 seconds on a dry, clean griddle.

Answer (score 4):

It's a late answer, but I do this all the time when I'm feeling lazy and don't want to make traditional roti. Heat up oil to 300 to 350 in a skillet .about 2 inches of oil. Or use your deep fryer at 350, just make sure it's large enough. The most important  thing is your oil needs to be up to temperature.  As soon as you toss in the tortilla it should automatically  pop and bubble up .count to 15 seconds and flip for 10 more seconds....let it drain on paper towels in a large bowl and cover with a kitchen towel to let the steam seep back in to keep it soft and moist....if it's crunchy it's because  your oil wasn't hot enough or it just sat too long frying...the while frying  process shouldn't exceed 25 seconds. 
By the way I used the burrito tortilla flour type. Burritos  are bigger.

Answer (score 2):

A tortilla is always going to get hard when deep fried as it's very thin and dry. There's no air or moisture to puff up in a tortilla, so I don't see how you would be able to make authentic poori with them. I've never made them myself but my understanding is that you need to make a dough, roll it to about 1cm thick and fry it.

Answer (score 1):

While preparing the dough, add a tablespoon of semolina that's already been soaked in warm water and a little sugar. You are sure to get your pooris to puff up. Its a thumb rule for preparing pooris. They'll be crisp when fried but cool down and become soft.